# Blazor List Rendering Issue (JsInterop) - GIT LINK INCLUDED

Tags: c#, blazor, lifecycle, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I've written a bunch of wrappers for existing javascript components, often times from the JqWidgets library.  Specifically in this case my problem relates to the JqxWindow component.  I will paste all relevant code below, but first I will explain what's happening.

I have a list of objects (in this case assignments).  Whenever an assignment is added to the list the it creates a component that I wrote as a wrapper around the JqxWindow and opens a new window.  The creation of windows works as expected.

The problem:  When I remove an item from the list, the page re-renders and always removes the last item in my list from a rendering perspective.  There are no errors.  I'm not 100% sure how to solve this and that's why I'm posting here.

Here is a link to the Git: https://github.com/TCrosmanDSI/JqWindowExample

Comment: Note that the list is correctly modified, and that if I were to render with out javascript interop, there would be no issues.  This problem relates to the events raised when modifying a list to javascript.

Comment: Are you saying when you remove from the list you don't want the item to disappear from the view?

Answer (score 2):

Use the @key so the renderer knows what items have changed

```
   <JqxWindowComponent @key="@windowId" Title="@windowId" InstanceId="@windowId" RemoveCallback="@DestroyWindow">
```

Comment: In not at home to try yet.  I thought I tried this and it didn’t work...but if it does I’ll select your answer! TY!

Comment: That worked!  Only difference is it needed to be lowercase "@key="@windowId"".  I've voted your answer as the correct answer thank you!

Comment: Hi Tom, to accept an answer as the solution, please click the green tick below the voting arrows.